# How to take stored procedure backup as i already uninstalled wamp?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, wamp

I uninstalled WAMP and i reinstalled it on another drive .
I have taken all folder from `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data` to `D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data` for database.
It takes all tables and data but not stored procedures.

Can any one explain me where is location of stored procedures files so that i will restore it again?

Comment: You cannot move MySQL 5.5 data into a MYSQL 5.6 environment and expect it to just work

Comment: @RiggsFolly then how come OP moved data ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i moved my all databases with tables but it did not move stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just copy databases between different versions of the MySQL database manager. Things change when version numbers change.

I think you will have to reinstall the D:\wamp version of WAMPServer to undo the mistake of copying mysql5.5 data to a mysql5.6 environment.

- Do an uninstall
- Manually delete all d:\wamp
- Reinstall onto D:
- Check basic stuff works
- Stop WAMPServer

Now copy your backup of `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data` to `D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data` **NOTE** you should now have 2 folders under `d:/wamp/bin/mysql`

So now you have 2 versions of MySQL installed and available on your new instance of WAMPServer.

- Start WAMPServer
- Switch to the old MySQL version

  left click wampmanager->MySQL->Version and click on 5.5.24
- Take a backup of all the databases you want to migrate to the new version of MySQL. Only backup YOUR databases not those you didnt create yourself!
- Switch to the new version of MySQL

  left click wampmanager->MySQL->Version and click on 5.6.17
- Now restore all your databases

You can now either leave the old version of MySQL there and available to switch to if you want or you can stop WampServer and delete the `D:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24` folder. Then restart, and it should no longer be there availabel to switch to.

Comment: i will do this and let you know